# How to make TextField Material UI component start with white text and underline

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to make my entire material UI TextField tag white. The label and the border, both off focus and on focus.

The on focus is all white, but I can't get the off-focus to be white. I see it in the dev tools as, but it must not be specific enough. I've even tried !important, but that still doesn't take priority over the original color.

I've tried about half a dozen methods and only have been able to get the on focus to work. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

```
import React from 'react';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';

const styles = theme => ({
    eventWrap: {
        width: '90%',
        margin: '0 auto',
        '$ eventInput': {
            color: 'white',
        },
    },
    eventExplaination: {
        fontSize: '25px',
        marginBottom: '50px',
    },
    root: {
        color: "white !important",
        borderColor: 'white !important',
      },
    input: {
        color: "white !important",
        borderColor: 'white !important',
      }
});

const CssTextField = withStyles({
    root: {
        '& label.Mui-focused': {
            color: 'white',
        },
        '& .MuiInput-underline:after': {
            borderBottomColor: 'white',
        },
    },
  })(TextField);

class Event extends React.Component {

    nextSection = () => {
        if(this.props.event !== '') {
            this.props.nextSection( 'emotions' )
        } else {
            alert('you must write in a situation or event')
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { classes } = this.props;
        return(
            <div className={classes.eventWrap}>
                <p className={classes.eventExplaination}>Write out an event or situation that made you feel anxious. Keep it factual, leave out all feelings about it.</p>
                <CssTextField
                    id="custom-css-standard-input"
                    label="Type in Event/Situation"
                    value={this.props.event}
                    onChange={(e) => this.props.updateEvent( e.target.value )}
                    placeholder="Event/Situation"
                    fullWidth
                    className={classes.root}
                    InputProps={{ className: classes.input }}
                    color="primary"
                />
                <button onClick={() => this.nextSection()}>Next</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(Event);
```

Comment: Can you also post the screenshot of the UI and the Styles on dev tools, pls?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const WhiteTextField = withStyles({
  root: {
    '& .MuiInputBase-input': {
      color: '#fff', // Text color
    },
    '& .MuiInput-underline:before': {
      borderBottomColor: '#fff8', // Semi-transparent underline
    },
    '& .MuiInput-underline:hover:before': {
      borderBottomColor: '#fff', // Solid underline on hover
    },
    '& .MuiInput-underline:after': {
      borderBottomColor: '#fff', // Solid underline on focus
    },
  },
})(TextField);
```